# Google apps script: embed two y-axis chart in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I embed a two y-axis chart in a spreadsheet using GAS? I need something similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nuno/Lf8fk52b/)

This is my code:

```
var range = grafData.getRange(2, 1, 10, 2) 
  var chart = sheetGraf.newChart()
  .setPosition(2, 1, 0, 0)
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
  .addRange(range)
  .setOption('title', 'Sales and Profitability')
  .setOption('series', {0: {axis: 'sales'}, 1: {axis: 'profitability'}})
  .setOption('axes', {y: { sales: {label: 'sales'}, profitability: {side: 'right', label: 'profitability'}}})
  .build();
  sheetGraf.insertChart(chart);
```

Which is returning:
[image: Chart]

The data source is being picked correctly:

[image: Datasource]

Idealy, I'd have a combo chart with profitability as a line in the secondary axis, but that isn't possible, right? So, how do I have 2 columns and 2 y-axis?

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the cell format of the column "Profitability" to text. In the Spreadsheet select that column then go to Format -> Number -> Plain Text. Then the chart will take those values as reference instead of values for the chart. try it and let me know if it did't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it didn't work very well (see http://postimg.org/image/4p5pcv7x9/) . Also, I need to do the whole process using the script.

Comment: you're right, i tested with the values of profitability in column A and sales in column B. you could try it that way.  i'll keep testing though.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this.

Comment: You're right. I was not able to do the same as the fiddle example you provided. May be you can raise this issue in the Apps script issues website to add this functionality. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Comment: I have submitted an issue here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5717&thanks=5717&ts=1454438327

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can have dual-Y axes in Google Charts:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['date', 'data1', 'data2', 'percentage'],
         [ "1 Mar", 289,  94, 0.10],  [ "2 Mar", 295,  96, 0.20],  [ "3 Mar", 300, 104, 0.30],
         [ "4 Mar", 306, 124, 0.40],  [ "5 Mar", 311, 142, 0.50],  [ "6 Mar", 317, 153, 0.60],  
         [ "7 Mar", 322, 158, 0.70],  [ "8 Mar", 328, 164, 0.80],  [ "09Mar", 334, 164, 0.90],  
         ["10 Mar", 339, 168, 0.80],  ["11 Mar", 345, 169, 0.70],  ["12 Mar", 351, 180, 0.60],  
         ["13 Mar", 357, 190, 0.50],  ["14 Mar", 363, 200, 0.40],  ["15 Mar", 369, 210, 0.30],  
         ["16 Mar", 375, 220, 0.20],  ["17 Mar", 381, 230, 0.10],  ["18 Mar", 387, 235, 0.00],  
         ["19 Mar", 393, 240, -0.10],  ["20 Mar", 399, 250, -0.20],  ["21 Mar", 406, 245, -0.30],  
         ["22 Mar", 412, 235, -0.40],  ["23 Mar", 418, 235, -0.50],  ["24 Mar", 425, 240, -0.60],  
         ["25 Mar", 431, 245, -0.70],  ["26 Mar", 438, 255, -0.80],  ["27 Mar", 444, 260, -0.90],  
         ["28 Mar", 451, 276, -0.80],  ["29 Mar", 458, 280, -0.70],  ["30 Mar", 464, 295, -0.60], 
         ["31 Mar", 471, 310, -0.50], 
        ]);
        var options = {
          title: 'Leads',
          hAxis: {showTextEvery: 5},
          vAxes: {0: {viewWindowMode:'explicit',
                      viewWindow:{
                                  max:510,
                                  min:82
                                  },
                      gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},
                      },
                  1: {gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},
                      format:"#%"},
                  },
          series: {0: {targetAxisIndex:0},
                   1:{targetAxisIndex:0},
                   2:{targetAxisIndex:1},
                  },
          colors: ["red", "green", "orange"],
          chartArea:{left:100,top:100, width:500, height:150},
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_id'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>

<div id="chart_id" style="width: 800px; height: 300px;"></div>
</html>
```

Working example here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/electronicsguy/Ltfvuk2y/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up an example here. You can insert a chart through scripts like this.

```
            function sheetChart(){
              try{
                var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById( DriveApp.getFilesByName('testSheet').next().getId() );
                sheet.insertImage(myChart(),1,1 )
              } catch(err){
                Logger.log(err);
              }
            }

            function myChart() {
              try{
              var data = Charts.newDataTable()
                  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Month')
                  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'In Store')
                  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Online')
                  .addRow(['January', 10, 1])
                  .addRow(['February', 12, 1])
                  .addRow(['March', 20, 2])
                  .addRow(['April', 25, 3])
                  .addRow(['May', 30, 4])
                  .build();

              var chart = Charts.newAreaChart()
                  .setDataTable(data)
                  .setStacked()
                  .setRange(0, 40)
                  .setTitle('Sales per Month')
                  .build();
              }catch(err){
                Logger.log(err);
              }
              return chart.getBlob();
            }
```

From there you can edit to collect the values on the rows and columns you are needing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My question is how to have 2 y-axis on the chart. A primary, on the left, and a secondary on the right. The first would have the sales data and the second the profitability data. Your script worked perfectly, but the chart contains only one y-axis. See for example: https://jsfiddle.net/nuno/Lf8fk52b/

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late but perhaps useful for others, also, this is a workaround - not a solution.

I was trying to generate a batch of spreadsheets with dual-y charts from a folder containing csv files and ran into this same problem.

The workaround is to create 'template' spreadsheet and manually set up the chart in the UI, setting up the axis (and whatever else) with a sample data range then clear the data the chart was using. In your script create a copy of that spreadsheet and paste in your new data each time (using .setValues with an array for example). The chart will be generated with the correct dual-y setup each time and adapts to different sized ranges.

For example, create copy of template file like so,

```
var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("<target_folder_id_goes_here>");
var ssTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById("<template_file_id_goes_here>");
var ssFile = ssTemplate.makeCopy("filename", targetFolder);
```

After that you can always edit the chart further with chart.modify()

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#modify